# python selenium switch_to_frame not working for me

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click the element below in python selenium chrome web driver.

```
<a href="javascript: d.o(18);" class="node">Maintenance</a>
```

It's working after switch right frame.

```
browser.switch_to_frame("navigation")
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Maintenance').click()
browser.find_element_by_link_text('Restore Default Settings').click()
```

But after successful click the 'Restore Default Settings') new page displaying in frame 3,so that adding the following code. (main is frame 3)

```
browser.switch_to_frame("main")
browser.find_element_by_name('loadConfig').click()
```

But this time, I have timeout error. 
It looks not recognized this frame3 in the code.

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

This is frame source.

```
<frameset rows="61,*" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
    <frame name="header" src="/cgi-bin/status_new.asp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <frameset cols="*,220,780,*" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
        <frame src="about:blank">
        <frame name="navigation" src="/cgi-bin/navigation-left.asp" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <frame name="main" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" src="/cgi-bin/status_deviceinfo.asp">
        <frame src="about:blank">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Do anybody know why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*? Selectors seem to be correct. Share exception log

Comment: I mean it actually not clicked with that selector.

Comment: So you mean that you make a click and nothing happened? No exception, just no reaction from web-app, right?

Comment: In fact, there is an error mostly displaying  NoSuchElementException is displayied

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='node' and contains(text(), 'Maintenance')]"

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared you can use the following line of code :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='node' and contains(text(), 'Maintenance')]").click()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the following error messages. 

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='node' and contains(text(), 'Maintenance')]"}

Comment: Can you show some more of the `outerHTML` from the top?